# Delay and queue animation in a function - how can I optimise this by removing duplicate code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I have this script that moves a box around the screen and the loops the second part of the movement.  I have altered the code to drop another three boxes (4 in total) into the animation so the boxes follow each other around the screen.

I want it to work exactly like it does, but I'm sure there's a much better way of doing this:

[Here's a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NF6LU/](http://jsfiddle.net/NF6LU/)

JS

```
function animateNode() {
    $('.node').animate({top: '425px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node2').animate({top: '425px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node3').animate({top: '425px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node4').animate({top: '425px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node').animate({marginLeft: '-284px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node2').animate({marginLeft: '-284px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node3').animate({marginLeft: '-284px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node4').animate({marginLeft: '-284px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node').animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node2').animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node3').animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node4').animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node2').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node3').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
    $('.node4').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
}
$('.node').delay(1500).animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1000, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node2').delay(3000).animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1000, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node3').delay(4500).animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1000, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node4').delay(6000).animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1000, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 1500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node2').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 1500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node3').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 1500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$('.node4').animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 1500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
$(function(){
    animateNode();
    setInterval(animateNode, 2000);
});
```

HTML

```
<span class="node"></span>
<span class="node2"></span>
<span class="node3"></span>
<span class="node4"></span>
```

CSS

```
span.node, span.node2, span.node3, span.node4{
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
```

Comment: You can put this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com , StackOverflow is for code that doesn't work, CodeReview is for code that works, but ineffiecently or redundant

Comment: @AlienArrays Cool, I didn't know that existed – thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to change animateNode to animate just one class like this

```
function animateNode() {
      //animate each node 
      $('.node').animate({top: '425px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true })
                .animate({marginLeft: '-284px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true })
                .animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1800, easing : 'linear', queue: true })
                .animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 2500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
}
$(".node").each(function(i,n){
    //animate each node with increment on delay 
    $(this).delay(1500*(i+1)).animate({top: '157px'}, { duration: 1000, easing : 'linear', queue: true })
           .animate({marginLeft: '264px'}, { duration: 1500, easing : 'linear', queue: true });
});
$(function(){
    animateNode();
    setInterval(animateNode, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NF6LU/1/